# Is there any way to keep a call to TDataset.Edit while controls are disabled from requiring a layout refresh upon enabling controls?

Tags: delphi

This is a bit involved, so bear with me.

`TDataset.Edit` calls `SetState(dsEdit);`, which calls `DataEvent(deUpdateState, 0);`

`TDataSet.DataEvent`, when called with a parameter of `deUpdateState`, if you've disabled controls on your dataset, it sets a flag that will send around a `deLayoutChange` event when controls are re-enabled, which according to the documentation signifies somewhat vaguely that "The layout of data in a data-aware control changed."

When the control being re-enabled is a data-bound grid, this can cause some very expensive resets, forcing the entire grid to be re-laid-out.  On a large dataset with lots of rows and columns, this can take several seconds, even if you didn't do anything while controls were disabled that affects the layout of the grid.

Is there any way to keep this from happening?  `SetState` is not virtual.  `DataEvent` is virtual, but the `FEnableEvent` field that it uses to set this up is not accessible from derived classes.  There doesn't seem to be any way to work around this without gross hackery. (RTTI surgery, overlay classes, etc.)  Does anyone know of a better way to pull it off?

Comment: Have you tried using TClientDataSet clone of the original dataset for the edit?  Of course, you would have to locate the appropriate record in the clone before editing.

Comment: What do you mean by "layout refresh" and "forcing the entire grid to be re-laid-out"? can you give some code to reproduce?

Comment: If you declare a class helper, you __do__ have access to the helped class' private members provided that you prefix them with `Self.`

Comment: @Marjan: If you declare a class helper, you have access to their *protected* members.

Comment: __And__ their private members, provided you use them through `Self.privatemember`.

Comment: @kobik: Not easily.  The code in question involves a very large dataset (thousands of rows, about 150 columns) and an expensive DevExpress grid component, all of which is details that are not relevant to the actual question being asked.

Comment: If all that is not relevant (I suspect the DevExpress grid to be the faulty member), your Q should be "how to access a private class field". Am I right?

Comment: @MasonWheeler can you edit the question in either two ways: provide a small reproducing example using only components included Delphi where you can put breakpoints to see the behaviour, or explain better with the current application where to put breakpoints inside the RTL/VCL to observe this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that your dataset is connected to a DevExpress grid, I would start looking there. Wrap your code that does the editing with a cxgrid.BeginUpdate and cxgrid.EndUpdate and a try/finally block.

```
MycxGrid.BeginUpdate;
try
   {Do some data editing}
finally
  MycxGrid.EndUpdate;
end;
```

This alone may be able to solve your problem. If it doesn't, look in the DevExpress help files TcxDBDataModeController.SmartRefresh and TcxDBDataModeController.SyncMode.

Without seeing your code I'm only guessing. But I had very similar performance problems to yours before I discovered the BeginUpdate/EndUpdate combination.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about TcxGrid, but maybe you could try to solve this at the control's side, and override `TcxGrid`'s `DataLink.LayoutChanged`, or another method from the grid itself.

As `TDBGrid` analogy:

- `TCustomDBGrid.CreateDataLink` is dynamic and can be overriden, so that you can inject your own `TGridDataLink` derivative on a `TDBGrid` descendent.
- `TGridDataLink.LayoutChanged` is virtual and can be overriden, this is option 1.
- `TGridDataLink.LayoutChanged` calls `FGrid.LayoutChanged`.
- `TCustomDBGrid.LayoutChanged` is also virtual, making it option 2.